# How to add footer to each ViewController of the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am a beginner to iPhone development.

I have added side-menu with **SWRevealViewController**.

[Github SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

Here is my code for side-menu

```
func sideMenus(){
        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 250
            revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 160
            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
```

But I am stuck now. I am struggling over add a footer to the app now.

I don't want to use tabbar controller. because I have just a single image in the footer. Can you guys help me to add the footer to my app?

Thanks

Comment: In whole app your footer is displayed or not?

Comment: there is no information what kind of footer you want.... I mean you can make it totally custom and add a zivile and set the size and constraints... If you have a collection or table view there are functions to provide you information about header/footer as well

Comment: share your design, plz

Comment: not displayed. adding footer is remaining part.

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2724596/76ae99a08eca120ce3adca28751729ea

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a UI element displaying the footer to each of your `ViewController`s. The easiest choice for your design seems to be a `UIImageView` and load the image representing your sponsor text+image to it.

Another solution would be to add a `UITabBar` of `UIToolBar` to each of your `ViewController` with no buttons and set the image as the background image of your tab bar to tool bar. You can do this either in `Storyboard` or from code.

Comment: i am adding the imageview there but it is hiding behind the footer

Comment: What do you mean behind the footer? What footer do you have?